# How do I parent a bone to another bone for an imported model?

Tags: armature, bones

I have an imported character model where the sword is floating near the ground and I'm trying to get it to be in the correct place near the hand.

There is already a bone on the handle of the sword which is called `sword_1` and it has a dashed black line to another bone which cannot be selected and doesn't seem to have a name (see picture).

There is another bone called `weapon_root` which is exactly where the weapon needs to be, near the end of the dashed black line, but I don't know how to move the sword there.

I have tried to make the `weapon_root` the parent of `sword_1`, but it didn't move the sword at all and it didn't seem to do anything because in the bone hierarchy they were still at the same level.

What should I do to get the `sword_1` bone to follow the `weapon_root` bone origin?

[image: The dashed black line of the sword_1 bone]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotted black line is called a relationship line, and it reveals that some kind of connection, either a parenting connection or a constraint connection, already exists between Sword1 and whatever this unnamed bone is. In either case, you will probably want to break this connection and start over. With the Sword1 bone selected, go to the *Constraints* tab in the Properties Panel, to the right of your 3D View, and check whether anything shows up. The relationship line is probably coming from something that will be found here. The other place you can check, but seems less likely, is the *Object* tab (**not** *Object Data* tab), and look under the Relations section, to see if the bone has a parent. If you found any connections, remove them. If you found none, then select the whole armature in Object Mode, and then tab into Edit Mode, then select the Sword1 bone, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, and choose **Clear Parent**. Now your Sword1 bone should still be part of the armature, but shouldn't move with any part of it during posing. Go into Pose Mode, and move the Sword1 bone to the hand position. It might be a good idea to make sure the armature is in its rest pose before doing this, which can be activated in the *Object Data* tab, under the *Skeleton* section, where you'll see two buttons, *Pose Position*, and *Rest Position*. Choose Rest Position to see the rest pose. Once you've activated the Rest Position, however, you can't move any bones until you return to the *Pose Position*. So after activating the Rest Postion, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and from the *Apply* menu, choose *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*. Now return to the Pose Position. You shouldn't have to do this again. It's a kind of calibration effort to ensure that you're working from the rest pose before adding constraints. If you add constraints without being in the rest pose first, weird things can happen.

Finally, while in Pose Mode, select Sword1 and create a **Child Of** constraint for it, and point this constraint to the hand IK target bone as the constraint's target. You will want to press the *Clear Inverse* button after creating the constraint to get the sword to remain where you placed it. It should follow the hand now when moving the IK target, and by keyframing the influence slider for the constraint, the sword can be released by the hand, or retrieved by it, any time you want.